# Can a variable reference itself at creation time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading the exemple : (for Sequelize, a NodeJS ORM) :

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {
  username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Task) // HERE !!! <-----
      }
    }
});
```

In the `associate` method, I call a function of `User`. The code seems to work but I wonder how is it possible that `User` is defined as...it's not yet defined...

Comment: because it won't be evaluated until the function is called

Comment: Isn't this the whole reason `var a = setInterval(function(){clearInterval(a);});` works?